# extract-text-webpack-plugin error npm install

Tags: css, npm, webpack

I get error when trying to install extract-text-webpack-pluginpm install

```
extract-text-webpack-plugin --save-devapp@0.1.0 /home/g/learn/web-app/ema/src/main/app
├─┬ extract-text-webpack-plugin@2.1.0 
│ ├── async@2.3.0 
│ └── loader-utils@1.1.0 
└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY webpack@^2.2.0

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.0.17 (node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.17: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN extract-text-webpack-plugin@2.1.0 requires a peer of webpack@^2.2.0 but none was installed.
```

Also tried this:

```
npm install extract-text-webpack-plugin@2.2.0 --save-dev
```

Not working.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you try to install extract-text-webpack-plugin for webpack2 ( 
`UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY webpack@^2.2.0`)

but you have already installed webpack1, so you should use extract plugin for webpack 1

```js
npm install --save-dev extract-text-webpack-plugin@1.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

These are all warnings, not errors. That means the package has been successfully installed, but you might need another package to make it work correctly. See [npm - peerDependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#peerdependencies).

You can safely ignore the `fsevents` warnings. It is a package that is exclusively used on macOS for watching changes on its file system.

On the other hand, you need to resolve the unmet peer dependency `webpack`. The latest version of the `extract-text-webpack-plugin` depends on webpack 2 (`v2.2.0` was the first official release of webpack 2). You're probably using webpack 1 and you have two options to resolve that. You can either install webpack 2, which would be recommended at this point. You might need to change your config a little. Have a look at the official [Migration Guide](https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/) to see what you need to change.

```
npm install webpack@latest --save-dev
```

If you can't or don't want to upgrade to webpack 2, you can use an older version of `extract-text-webpack-plugin` that was meant to be used with webpack 1.

```
npm install extract-text-webpack-plugin@1.0.1 --save-dev
```